# web scraping returns 'None'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and I am trying to build a web scraping algorthm.

I am trying to scrape the 'href' urls:
[image: Picture of the html from the website]

my code:

```
URL = 'https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/team.php?team=UTA'

page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

for link in soup.find_all({"aria-colindex" : "3"}):

    print(link.get('href'))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service)
```

but this returns nothing. I have also tried {'style' : "width: 96px; left: 190px; top: 0px;"} insteed of {"aria-colindex" : "3"}, but this also returns 'None'. Don't know what I am doing wrong , so any help would be much appreciated:)

Comment: Try opening the site with the driver, not requests, then use beautifulsoup after that

Comment: Please no pictures, just copy-paste the source code! Thanks

Comment: `soup.find_all({"aria-colindex" : "3"})` will find the `div` tags, which do not have an `href` attribute, so it makes sense that `link.get('href')` would return `None`.  You need to look at the `a` child of each `div`.

Comment: ok, but how do I do that? Thanks for the response:)

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded dynamically from an [api](https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/tables/team-schedule.php?team=UTA). It's easier to retrieve the links from the api directly. Here's a `pandas` implementation:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
df = pd.read_json('https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/tables/team-schedule.php?team=UTA')
df['url'] = df['score'].apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x).find('a')['href'])
df.to_csv('output.csv') #export to csv
```